# Github only cloning improvements

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am one of the remote repository collaborators and i want to only clone the improvements of another collaborator after he made a new commit. How do I do that? How to clone only latest improvements instead of a whole massive repository? Is there a specific command I have to issue? I guess that if i do `git clone *link to the repository` it will just clone the whole repository that isn’t required

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "clone only latest improvements"? Do you just want to update the repository that already exists on your computer?

Comment: Can you explain what you've done so far? Have you cloned the repository previously? How did you clone it? Do you have a link to the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the repository cloned on your computer already and the changes are being made directly to the master branch, you would simply run [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) inside the repository's directory.

This will "fetch" (download) the changes to the remote repository and then "merge" them into your local branch.